# css style is broken in chrom

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

Development Environment
・react
・typescript

I'm using the react-paginate library. I use css to style it.
When I look at it on my mac chrome, the style is not broken, but when I look at it on my windows chrome, the css style is broken.
ReactPaginate has a className of pagination and is styled with css.

```
 <div>
    <ReactPaginate
      previousLabel={'<'}
      nextLabel={'>'}
      breakClassName={'break-me'}
      pageCount={3}
      pageRangeDisplayed={3}
      onPageChange={(data) => onCahngePage(data)}
      containerClassName={'pagination'}
      activeClassName={'active'}
    />
  </div>
```

```
.pagination {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  li {
    position: relative;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: auto;
    a {
      position: absolute;
      left: 4px;
      font-size: 15px;
      background: white;
      outline-style: none;
      color: white;
    }
    animation: ripple 0.7s linear infinite;
    &.active {
      background: blue;
      color: blue;
      a {
        color: blue;
        background: blue;
        overflow: auto;
      }
    }
    @keyframes ripple {
      0% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(184, 226, 250, 0.733), 0 0 0 0.1em rgba(184, 226, 250, 0.733),
          0 0 0 0.2em rgba(184, 226, 250, 0.733), 0 0 0 0.3em rgba(184, 226, 250, 0.733);
      }
      100% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.1em rgba(184, 226, 250, 0.733), 0 0 0 0.2em rgba(184, 226, 250, 0.733),
          0 0 0 0.4em rgba(184, 226, 250, 0);
      }
    }
  }
  .previous {
    display: none;
  }
  .next {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

> 

imageA
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVCTq.jpg)

imageB
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EixxA.png)

Comment: Have you looked at your elements using Chrome Devtools to see what's applying and what isn't?

Comment: I don't have a windows environment.

Comment: On a mac chrom, there is nothing unusual when I open devtool.

Comment: I think you'll get more useful answers if you describe what specifically is broken on windows (and how you're seeing it if you don't have a windows environment?), ideally with a reproducible example. It may be that you've just run into a cross-platform rendering issue, but without details we won't be able to see what it is.